# Explorer preview pane & DOTX files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

Word seems to 'bug-out' when previewing a template file from windows explorer's preview pane. The file will display a preview but cannot be opened in word until `word.exe` process is killed.

This behaviour does not occur on any other type of file. The only information I have seen was this [less than helpful post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/word/thread/241b5832-4bdd-48c7-b78a-168f0a720778).

Comment: First I heard of this (since I don't use the Preview pane), but tested and confirmed. As the MS Tech Support chap said: "it is a design issue, and it will not be fixed". Clearly a bug but supposed to be "by design"? In any case, I don't see any way to get around this, other than by turning Preview off. BTW, no reason to hope it will help, but have you confirmed that 64-bit Office behaves the same way?

Comment: This seems like a pretty serious fault for enterprise customers.

Comment: Yeah it is. Maybe, just maybe, they fixed it in Win8 + Office 2013...